# Il mio piede è letterale, quello della pagina figurato, ma quelli del tavolo e della montagna?

Tags: idioms, figures-of-speech

(Ho una tremenda difficoltà a trovare tag adatti: perché non ci sono tag come [astratto](/questions/tagged/astratto), [concreto](/questions/tagged/concreto), [figurato](/questions/tagged/figurato)?)

---

Credevo di sapere la differenza tra *concreto* e *figurato*, ma indagando bene, mi rendo conto di avere profondi dubbi in merito a questo argomento come a tanti altri.

Ho scelto il titolo della domanda per renderla più appetibile, ma credo sia inequivocabilmente identificabile con una domanda più precisa:

##### Che cosa rende l'utilizzo di una parola concreto o figurato?

[Con una veloce ricerca](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/in-senso-figurato/) ho trovato esempi che mi suscitano meno dubbi.

> Ha preso la mela e se l'è mangiata

Qui *mangiare* è letterale, concreto: la mela viene meccanicamente messa in bocca, per intero o pezzo per pezzo, ulteriormente maciullata coi denti, etc etc.

> Ha preso da parte la collega e se l'è mangiata

Qui *mangiare* è figurato, perché *mangiare una persona vuol dire riempirla di rimproveri e minacce* (poi al mio paese ci sono anche altre possibili sfumature, ma va be'). Il punto è che qui tutta la "meccanica" del mangiare non ha avuto luogo, per cui sono sicuro del fatto che l'utilizzo di *mangiare* sia in questo caso figurato.

Ma tornando all'esempio del titolo, mi sento un po' a disagio.

La pagina non è nemmeno lontanamente antropomorfa; se non mi accorgo del suo spessore non abbiamo in comune nemmeno il numero di dimensioni! Quindi va bene, quello della pagina, tipicamente il *pie'* invece che il *piede*, è figurato.

Ma la montagna? I suoi piedi, in una situazione di normalità (e.g. la montagna non è franata completamente, né il materiale di cui erano fatti i piedi è in realtà nel calcestruzzo del soffitto della mia casa), sono in basso in un senso "gravitazionale", come i miei in una situazione di ordinarietà (se non sono in basso vuol dire che sto dormendo, attività durante cui non parlo di piedi, probabilmente). I piedi della montagna sostengono ciò che ci sta sopra, come i miei.

E lo stesso vale per il tavolo, che per di più è vagamente più antropomorfo della montagna (non ci ho speso tempo, ma credo che siano stati e sono ancora prodotti e venduti svariati tavoli a forma di persona a carponi) e ha un insieme numerabile di piedi.

Il pie' di pagina non regge un tubo, né è gravitazionalmente in basso. Nelle situazioni più ordinarie è alla stessa quota del resto del libro, tipicamente adagiato su una superficie orizzontale.

Allora cosa significa figurato e cosa significa concreto?

Comment: Piè, con l'accento, non con l'apostrofo. Quanto al senso figurato, “pes” era già usato in latino con tutti i significati menzionati e anche qualcuno in più: [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpes)

Comment: Accidenti. E credo di averlo pure letto di recente che si scrive così!

Comment: Anche in inglese si usano "header” e “footer” per ciò che si scrive in testatina e piè di pagina. Non credo sia una “personificazione”, solo una similitudine.

Comment: Mi sembra una questione di lana caprina, più formale che sostanziale, ma non lo intendo come critica. Io mi ci crogiolo, nelle questioni di lana caprina! :) Penso che un buon punto di partenza sia un'ampia voce di dizionario come [questa](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piede). Lì sembra che i sensi che dici non siano considerati né propri né figurati, ma “estesi”: “Per estens[ione], la parte più bassa di un oggetto, spec. di un mobile, sulla quale l’oggetto stesso poggia o sembra poggiare”.

Answer (score 4):

Come accennavo in un commento, gli usi relativi a mobili, montagne etc. non sono né letterali né figurati, ma *estensioni* (o più tecnicamente [“catacresi”](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/catacresi)) dell'uso primario. Le gambe e i piedi degli oggetti sono letteralmente in basso e li sostengono, e quindi non li considererei usi veramente figurati come invece, per esempio, in “togliti dai piedi” o “andare con i piedi di piombo”.

Answer (score 3):

L'opposto di figurato non è concreto, bensì letterale.
Figurato e letterale si riferiscono al significato che viene attribuito alla parola.

Le parole, infatti, hanno un significato proprio, di base, che indica in modo preciso una persona, un animale o un oggetto. Molte parole, però, hanno anche un significato figurato, legato al significato di base ma usato per fare dei paragoni, delle similitudini.

> Quella lumaca di mia sorella non è ancora pronta!

La parola lumaca non è usata con il suo significato letterale. Dire “quella lumaca di mia sorella” significa voler esprimere il fatto che mia sorella è una persona molto lenta.

Quando invece uso lumaca per indicare l'animale bavoso e strisciante la parola ha significato letterale.

Diversa cosa sono i nomi concreti e i nomi astratti.

Amore è un nome astratto, non è un oggetto fisico, mentre montagna è un nome concreto.

Quindi piè di pagina, gambe (non piedi) del tavolo e piedi della montagna sono nomi concreti (si riferiscono tutti a degli oggetti) il cui significato è di tipo figurato (sto espandendo l'uso della parola piede ad un significato che non è quello dell'oggetto fisico per cui nasce quella parola).

Comment: Interessante, e utili le precisazioni terminologiche, ma non condivido, per i motivi che spiego nella mia risposta. Forse il problema è che “letterale” e “figurato” non esauriscono necessariamente tutti i possibili usi di una parola.

Comment: Ciao, hai ragione, la tua risposta è più precisa sul significato assunto da piede nei casi citati, ma la domanda conclusiva e tutta l'esposizione del quesito chiedono un chiarimento su una contrapposizione che non esiste: concreto Vs figurato. Dovremmo fondere le risposte :-D